# Sending information from a servlet back to a Filter

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7, servlet-filters

I have an old web application, running on Tomcat 7, that uses a very rudimentary open-session-in-view mechanism provided by a filter:

```
@Override public void doFilter (ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain fc) 
    throws IOException, ServletException 
{
    try {
        HibernateUtil.beginTransaction();
        fc.doFilter(req, resp);
        HibernateUtil.commitTransaction();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Logger.exception(t, "processing servlet request");
        HibernateUtil.rollbackTransaction();
        throw new ServletException(t);
    }
}
```

I'm stuck with this now, and I think I'm running into one of the many flaws with OSIV (or at least this implementation of it) which is that I now want to be able to rollback transactions even *without* an exception being thrown. I want servlets to be able to control that, and I don't think I have much choice except to hack this functionality on somehow.

My question is: How can I communicate some sort of "rollback" flag from an arbitrary servlet back up to this filter? I want to be able to do something like this in the filter:

```
HibernateUtil.beginTransaction();
fc.doFilter(req, resp);
if (/* something that was set by a servlet/jsp */)
    HibernateUtil.rollbackTransaction();
else
    HibernateUtil.commitTransaction();
```

I'm not really sure what a reliable way to propagate information like that from a servlet back out to this filter is.

Comment: Request attributes or some other thread local value.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well that was easy. Sweet, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't advise using request attributes or thread-local variables, which has the following issues:

1. Your transaction is dependent on someone else having set a flag. If you work for a bank, I really don't wanna be a customer there.
2. Resource leaking if you don't clean up thread-local storage.
3. You can't write multithreaded code without manually copying stuff between thread-local storage.
4. If using request attribute, you'll have to extract the value in a Servlet and pass all the way to your DAO, assuming you're using a common multi layered architecture.

Instead, you can simply get the current transaction from the Hibernate session object and ask it to rollback. `Session.getTransaction().rollback()`. Best, scrap that code or find the person who wrote it and ask for a refund.